# if you have two exists how does it work?

Tags: mysql

The query I am analysing is below. I would like to understand how the second `EXISTS` works here. Is my understanding correct?  If not please explain me:

1. The Query looks at each record from `select cust_nofrom customers C1`.
2. The first record is checked against the first `NOT EXIST` query to make sure it does not exist. If it does not exist it returns `TRUE`, else `FALSE`. If `TRUE` it continues to be checked against the second `NOT EXIST` query and also returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

```
SELECT cust_no
FROM customers C1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM orders, order_details OD1
    WHERE orders.order_no = OD1.order_no
          AND orders.cust_no = C1.cust_no 
          AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM products
            WHERE OD1.prod_cod = products.prod_cod 
                  AND products.prod_cod = 'STAND'
          )
)
```

Comment: I think you've got it. The query's creator has an aversion to the word 'join', and uses a correlated subquery where, I suspect, an uncorrelated one would be more performative.

Comment: I believe you are correct also. Often a reason for using | NOT | EXISTS is to avoid multiplying rows that is so often the outcome of joining (and that can help to avoid select distinct or group by). But here the final outcome are rows that have no match, so LEFT JOINS could be used and only the unmatched rows returned by use of the where clause. e.g. `left join orders on orders.cust_no = C1.cust_no where orders.cust_no IS NULL`